# Navigation bar and viewpager on same activity

Tags: android, android-viewpager

In my app navigation drawer and viewpager are on same activity. I want to hide viewpager on clicking the item on navigation drawer.
I tried to set its visibility as GONE but it didn't work.
Pleaseeee tell me how to hide it thanks..
  Tab.setVisibility(ViewPager.GONE); this is the line I wrote in my code

On clicking drawer item fragment containing webview opens

Answer (score 0):

If you want to hide the ViewPager, you need to set it's visibility to View.GONE. Try

```
myViewPager.setVisibility(View.GONE);
```

instead. Currently you're setting the visibility on a Tab and not the ViewPager itself. They're 2 completely different things.